# how can i fetch the people i follow but they don't follow back?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, ajax, mysqli

so i have a table called `follow_sys` with three columns `id` and `follower` and `following` containing the usernames of followers and followed ,so i want to fetch all of the followers i follow but they don't follow me back, how can i do that ?

i tried a self join but it didn't work, i'm confused

```
    $sqlFollowing      = "SELECT * from follows_syds t1
                               join follows_syds t2 on
                               t1.follower != t2.following
                               where
                               t1.follower = ?
                               group by t1.id";
$Following         = $conn -> prepare($sqlFollowing);
$Following        -> bind_param('s',$getUser);
$Following        -> execute();
$FollowingGET      = $Following -> get_result();
$FollowingRows     = $FollowingGET -> num_rows;

while($b = $FollowingGET -> fetch_assoc()){

print_r($b);
echo "</br>";
}
```

Comment: Is the table called `follow_sys` now or `follow_syds`? You are grouping by `id` even though you state `containing the usernames instead of ids` How is that possible?

Comment: `follow_syds` i insert username wish is unique per every user into that table when a user follow someon, the follow and follower are varchar column

Comment: oh yes the id is a primary key actually

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work?  Did you get the wrong result, or an error, or ??

Comment: non matter what i do it gets all the follower i only want the people i follow but they don't follow me back